# Particle Swarm Optimization help for Real World problems?

Tags: neural-networks

I just completed watching the [Particle Swarm Optimization Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ3T575sbI8&feature=youtu.be), and I was wondering how to next apply this to a new set of data for which I want to optimize.

Let's say, for example I want to build a (crude) model for predicting security prices.  Let's say my objective function that I want to optimize is the [Sharpe Ratio](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sharperatio.asp) or Percent Profit.

Now, I can download a set of data from Yahoo, and clean it up in Matlab or Python to supply the objective function with the correct data.

But, my questions are as follows:

- How would PSO be used for a stock prediction application?
- How would I use the input data (like, from Yahoo) and use it in a general PSO algorithm?
- Are there any tutorials on how to apply PSO to a real world optimization or prediction problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think this is answerable. Optimization in this context means having a loss function to score alternative parameter choices. Your question doesn't describe a loss function, your inputs, or your parameters, so I don't know how this could be answerable. (Stocks are the data, but what is your model? How are prices related to your outcomes?)

Comment: That's what I'm sort of looking to have answered.  I'm not sure what else needs to go into addressing a real-world problem of this type.  Thanks.